# Qt Qml Reference Error mouse is not defined

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I want to get mouse X and mouse Y on map. I use mouse.x but I get an error that `"Reference Error mouse is not defined"`. In qt's signals I dont get error but in signals that I create I get error

Not error signal:

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
    onMouseXChanged: {
        var coordinate = mapview.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y))
        store_coordinate.store(coordinate)
        mainwindow.mapClickSignal()
        if (mouse.button === Qt.RightButton)
        {
            mainwindow.rightClickedMenuFreeSpace(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y),coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude)
        }
    }
    onPressed: {
        mouse.accepted = false
    }
}
```

Error signal:

```
Connections {
    target: mainwindow
    onSelectItem: {
        var coordinate = QtPositioning.coordinate(x, y)
        mapview.center =  coordinate
        mapview.update()
    }

    onRemoveAction: {
        var coordinate = mapview.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y))//error
        mainwindow.deleteAction(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude)
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I tried onRemoveAction:(mouse)=>                                                                                              and onRemoveAction:(mouseX,mouseY)=>

Comment: You will not have access to mouse.x and mouse.y in your signals. However, you can cheat by creating a global property that stores your mouse positions.
The parent of the mouse area could have two properties mouseX and mouseY updated with the onXMouseChanged handler of the mouse area. So mouseX and mouseY of the parent would be accessible in your connection by doing parent.mouseX and parent.mouseY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mouseEvent mouse` is passed as a parameter to only some signals (e.g. `onClicked`, `onPressed`). However, the `mouseEvent mouse` parameter is not available in all signal handlers in `MouseArea`, so, I wouldn't expect it to be available in `onMouseXChanged`. Also, the `mouse` parameter/property is not defined outside of `MouseArea`.

Consider setting the `id: mouseArea`, i.e.

```
    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
    }
```

Then in your `Connections` you can make use of `mouseArea.mouseX` and `mouseArea.mouseY`.

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#mouseX-prop
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#mouseY-prop

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [signal documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#signal-parameters).

`onMouseXChanged` is a property change signal handler which usually don't have parameters (at least the documentation isn't showing that). Therefore you need to set an id on the `MouseArea` to access the properties [mouseX/mouseY](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#mouseX-prop) which are equivalent to x/y of the `MouseEvent`.

`onPressed` and `onPositionChanged` are signal handler which provide parameters. To access those, you should assign a function to the handler. Both arrow functions and anonymous functions work.

Depending on the `target` of your `Connections` object the same applies. You should have a look into the documentation of the target and look at the signals, figure out which parameters are provided.

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    id: root
    width: 400
    height: 300
    visible: true

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton

        onMouseXChanged: {
            console.log("onMouseXChanged", Qt.point(mouseArea.mouseX, mouseArea.mouseY))
        }

        onPressed: function(mouse) {
            mouse.accepted = false
        }

        onPositionChanged: function(mouse) {
            console.log("onPositionChanged", Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y))
        }
    }


    Connections {
        target: mouseArea
        function onWheel(wheel) { console.log(wheel) }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I was curious why `mouse` is somehow available in `onMouseXChanged`, because usually only the signal handlers have parameters, but in this case the property change signal handler also has a parameter which isn't documented. To find out one needs to look at the source. In this case it is
`include/QtQuick/6.4.0/QtQuick/private/qquickmousearea_p.h`

```
Q_PROPERTY(qreal mouseX READ mouseX NOTIFY mouseXChanged)
...
void mouseXChanged(QQuickMouseEvent *mouse);
```

The outcome is "we shouldn't trust the documentation to much" :)